# Find and replace image path

Tags: arcpy, mxd, jpg, data-source

I have multiple mxd's with many company logos as jpg's.  We've moved the location of the logos from the F:\ drive to the C:\ drive.  I have a script that is supposed to change the path, but not sure where I enter the find/replace.  I did not write this script.

```
##Script used to change all JPEG images with old file paths to the new##

#import modules
import arcpy
import sys

#set environment
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
clean = 0

#loop through list and change all picture element file paths
for pic in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"PICTURE_ELEMENT"):
    path = pic.sourceImage
    pathNEW = path
    pathNEW = pathNEW.replace(r"F:\Logos\", "C:\GIS\Logos\")
    try:
        pic.sourceImage = pathNEW
    except:
        clean = 1
        pic.sourceImage = path


#refresh the active view
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

print "Auto changes complete!"
if clean == 1:
    print "One or more images need manual correction."
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please be user to [take the tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for an overview of our focused Q&A format. This script appears to run with the current active MXD. Have you tried to run it within ArcMap's Python window, with an example from your existing data? You would update lines 13-16.

Comment: I see no change from F: to C: as stated in your question, are you missing a line? There should be one of your replace statements changing the drive letter... but I would either upper() or lower() the pic.sourceImage before replacing, python is a case sensitive language. Consider using either arcpy.Exists() or os.path.exists() (and os.path.isfile()) to test that your pathNEW actually points to a file before setting the new path to pic.sourceImage.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This was an existing script that someone gave me stating it would do what I wanted.  So I had not made any adjustments to it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to match your updated question (updated script code).  There is a problem with the strings that your using in the `.replace()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `.replace()` in your updated code has some errors in the string syntax.  It should be:

```
    pathNEW = pathNEW.replace(r"F:\Logos", r"C:\GIS\Logos")
```

- The 'r' added before the second string tells Python to treat the '\' characters as literal '\' and not as special string code characters (which they are in normal Python strings)
- There should be NO '\' at the end of either string!  Even with the 'r' at the beginning of the string, the last character should not be a '\'.

See the "String Literals" section at:  https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html where it states that

> even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes

See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals

and:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash

Comment: It would be more robust if you changed the replace to pic.sourceImage.lower().replace(r"f:\old\directory", r"c:\directory\new") - case is important. Still worth a +1 though.

Comment: thanks for the help.  This is part of a two-step process I'm working through.  First is to change all files from .bmp to .jpg which I can do successfully.  But, they are still sourced to the F:\ drive.  I ran this new script and it changed everything from F to f, but did not replace with c:\.  Most path names are the same, I have a few logos who have gone out of business so I can delete those as needed.

new image source now looks like "f:\logos\hotels\hyattplace.jpg"

Comment: Here is my script. I guess we needed to add a subfolder

Comment: Thanks for sending the help documentation and your updated code edit.  It seems to be working.

Comment: That’s good to hear.  You should hit the big tick/check mark next to this answer if it solves your question satisfactorily.